# Generalized Matrix Multiplication without Numpy

Tags: python, matrix-multiplication

I want to make a system that allows me to input 2 matrixes, and it output a correct answer. I've gotten it to work with specifically a 1 x 3 * 3 x 2. But I want to make it more open ended. How could I do this?

```
# 1 x 3 by 3 x 2
def matmul(matA, matB):

    p1 = matA[0][0] * matB[0][0]
    p2 = matA[1][0] * matB[2][0]
    p3 = matA[2][0] * matB[4][0]
    
    num1 = p1 + p2 + p3
    
    p1 = matA[0][0] * matB[1][0]
    p2 = matA[1][0] * matB[3][0]
    p3 = matA[2][0] * matB[5][0]
    
    num2 = p1 + p2 + p3

    # Output is a 1 x 2 Matrix
    result = [num1, num2]
    print(result)

# ----------------------------------- #

# 1 x 3 Matrix
A = (
 [5],
 [-5],
 [10]
)

# 3 x 2 Matrix
B = (
 [-10], [13],
 [57], [-37],
 [-96], [15]
)

# Outputs a 1 x 2 Matrix
MatMult(A, B)
```

Comment: for matrix multiplication you have to iterate one matrix columnwise and the other rowwise. then add the product of each element to obtain the result of an specific cell. In your example you are using only the first index and letting the second index be 0, instead you can use a row col indexing system which will make it easier to iterate

Comment: you would use `nested for loops`.

Comment: [Look up the algorithm for generalized matrix multiplication](https://www.google.com/search?q=matrix+multiplication+algorithm). Then implement it. If you have a specific question about a problem you ran into while implementing the algorithm, please update your question with the details for that _specific_ problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# 1 x 3 Matrix
A = [ [5, -5, 10]]

# 3 x 2 Matrix
B = [
 [-10, 13],
 [57, -37],
 [-96, 15]
]

def mult_matx(A, B):
    
    rowsA = len(A)
    colsB = len(B[0])
    result = [[0] * colsB for i in range(rowsA)]
    
    for i in range(rowsA):
        
        # iterating by column by B
        for j in range(colsB):
            
            
            # iterating by rows of B
            for k in range(len(B)):
                
                result[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j]
 
    for r in result:
        print(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

I expect that you will find many example of this, but here is working code. In particular, you will use `nested for loops` or `nested list comprehension` to generate the final matrix.

```py
# Program to multiply two matrices using nested loops

# 3x3 matrix
X = [[12,7,3],
    [4 ,5,6],
    [7 ,8,9]]
# 3x4 matrix
Y = [[5,8,1,2],
    [6,7,3,0],
    [4,5,9,1]]
# result is 3x4
result = [[0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0]]

# iterate through rows of X
for i in range(len(X)):
   # iterate through columns of Y
   for j in range(len(Y[0])):
       # iterate through rows of Y
       for k in range(len(Y)):
           result[i][j] += X[i][k] * Y[k][j]

for r in result:
   print(r)
```

And here is an example of the same:
https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/examples/multiply-matrix